# jsonrpc method `payment_queryInfo` is being deprecated

Tags: polkadot-js, runtime-api, substrate-api-client

I saw this polkadot API document: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc/#payment
and it mentioned that the `payment_queryInfo` is deprecated and should use `api.call.transactionPaymentApi.queryInfo` instead.

Does this mean I can only use `queryInfo` by using JS SDK directly? or is there any RPC method that can replace this method?

Because when I search for supported rpc methods by invoking `rpc_methods`, it still returns `payment_queryInfo` as one of the supported methods, and I don't see other alternative RPC methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the time being the RPC is still available, but will soon be faded out, that's why it's marked as `deprecated`. You could use the `api.call.transactionPaymentApi.queryInfo` as you mentioned or, if you prefer using RPC, you could also use the RPC [`state_call`](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc/#callmethod-text-data-bytes-at-blockhash-bytes) with `TransactionPaymentApi_query_info` and the encoded extrinsic you'd like to know the fees of. Both alternatives are equivalent and will return the same result.